# Using int, double and long in calculation of powers

Tags: java, int, double, long-integer

I'm having trouble figuring out when to use int, double and long.

I'm working on calculating the power of an integer and return the result as long as the power provided is not a negative number.

For the assignment, I'm required to use the following code to start:

```
public static long powerN(int number, int power) {
```

Here's what I came up with:

```
public class PowerCalculator
{
/**
 * Calculate the non-negative power of an integer number. If a negative power is input, the method returns 1.
 * 
 * @param number The number to take power.
 * @param power The power factor to be taken to.
 * @return The calculation result after taking power of the integer number.
 */
    public static long powerN(int number, int power) {

       if (power > 0)
       {  
         double result = (Math.pow(number, power));  
         return result; 
       }
       else 
       {
         return 1; 
       }
    }
}
```

I know I'm messing up the use of int, double or long but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Have a look [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).

Comment: I suspect the purpose of the assignment was not to use `Math.pow` but to calculate the power by multiplying the right number of times. I would think that that was your teacher's intent in the assignment. If you do want to use `Math.pow`, you should learn about casting. For example to convert a double to a long you would say `(long) result`. But I don't think that is what they want.

Comment: hmm. You might be right. I guess I'd better clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it by yourself:

```
public static long powerN(
   int number, 
   int power
) {
   if(power == 0) return 1;
   int result = number;

   while(power > 1) {
      result*=number;
      power--;
   }

   return (long)result;
}
```

PS: This does not handle negative powers.

Comment: What is `result * number` if `result == 0`? Your method will always return 0.

Comment: I just edited my answer, I missed initializing result with number. result*=number is the same that saying result = result * number. @martin-m-j

Comment: Thanks. The assignment said we could come up with our own implementation so I stuck to math.pow and made the edit: (long) result. I just submitted the code. You guys have been very helpful.

Comment: This code doesn't work in a proper way.
1) x pow n will return x pow n+1
2) x pow 0 should return 1, but will return x*x

Comment: should be the while condition different? while(power > 1)  instead?

Answer (score 5):

Wait! If you're doing it yourself, use a faster algorithm like [Exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring), something like this:

```
long powerN(long number, int power){
    long res = 1;
    long sq = number;
    while(power > 0){
        if(power % 2 == 1){
            res *= sq; 
        }
        sq = sq * sq;
        power /= 2;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you'd like to use `Math.pow`:

```
public static long powerN(int number, int power) {
  return (long) Math.pow(number, power);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: Cast result of Math.pow to long:

```
public class PowerCalculator{
/**
 * Calculate the non-negative power of an integer number. If a negative power is input, the method returns 1.
 * 
 * @param number The number to take power.
 * @param power The power factor to be taken to.
 * @return The calculation result after taking power of the integer number.
 */
public static long powerN(int number, int power) {

    // write your code after this line
    if (power < 0){
        return 1;
    } else{
        return (long) Math.pow(number, power);
    }
```

Option 2: without using Math.pow

```
    public class PowerCalculator{
/**
 * Calculate the non-negative power of an integer number. If a negative power is input, the method returns 1.
 * 
 * @param number The number to take power.
 * @param power The power factor to be taken to.
 * @return The calculation result after taking power of the integer number.
 */
public static long powerN(int number, int power) {

    // write your code after this line
    long result = 1;
    while (power > 0) {
        result *= number;
        power--;
    }
    return result;
}
```